# How to generate entity files in NestJS and TypeORM

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I come from Java background, we had tools to generate Java entity(`DTOs`, `DAOs`, `JPAs`, etc ...) files from the database directly, am working now on `NestJS` project and using `TypeORM`, I have my tables ~ 30 table implmented on `MySQL`, is there away to generate the entity files

Comment: Have a look to https://github.com/Kononnable/typeorm-model-generator

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is generally a Database First Approach to ORM, TypeORM does not support that natively AFAIK.

My best suggestion would be to implement a JSON to TS model and then map the required columns with TypeORM decorators. That will be your best bet.

For now, you can implement independent tables and then go along with other tables. I know its a long process. But modern ORMs are made to work with Entity first method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sequelize-typescript-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript-generator#prerequisites) library to create the entity and models automatically based on schema and connection.

From the description:

> You can run this globally if you already install the package
>
> For the usage of the command
>
> ```
> -h, --host                  Database IP/hostname                      
> -p, --port                  Database port. Defaults:
>                             - MySQL/MariaDB: 3306
>                             - Postgres: 5432
>                             - MSSQL: 1433                             
> -d, --database              Database name                             
> -s, --schema                Schema name (Postgres only). Default:
>                             - public                                  
> -D, --dialect               Dialect:
>                             - postgres
>                             - mysql
>                             - mariadb
>                             - sqlite
>                             - mssql                        
> -u, --username              Database username                         
> -x, --password              Database password                         
> -t, --tables                Comma-separated names of tables to process
> -T, --skip-tables           Comma-separated names of tables to skip   
> -i, --indices               Include index annotations in the generated models
>                                                                     
> -o, --out-dir               Output directory. Default:
>                             - output-models                           
> -C, --case                  Transform tables and fields names
>                             with one of the following cases:
>                             - underscore
>                             - camel
>                             - upper
>                             - lower
>                             - pascal
>                             - const
>                             You can also specify a different
>                             case for model and columns using
>                             the following format:
>                             <model case>:<column case>
> -S, --storage               SQLite storage. Default:
>                             - memory                               
> -L, --lint-file             ES Lint file path                        
> -l, --ssl                   Enable SSL                               
> -r, --protocol              Protocol used: Default:
>                             - tcp                                     
> -a, --associations-file     Associations file path                    
> -g, --logs                  Enable Sequelize logs                    
> -n, --dialect-options       Dialect native options passed as json string.
> -f, --dialect-options-file  Dialect native options passed as json file path.                             
> -R, --no-strict             Disable strict typescript class declaration.
> ```
>
> Example of the command:

> ```
> stg \
> -D mysql \
> -h localhost \
> -p 3306 \
> -d myDatabase \ 
> -u myUsername \
> -x myPassword \
> --indices \
> --case camel \
> --out-dir pathofthegeneratedfiletakeplace \
> --clean \
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
    //app.module.ts
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { UserModule } from './user.resources/users.module';
    import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    import { UserEntity } from './user/entity/user.entity';

    @Module({
      imports: [
       TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
       type: 'mysql', 
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 3306, // By default
       username: 'YOUR_DB_USER',
       password: 'YOUR_DB_PASSWORD',
       database: 'YOUR_DB_NAME',
       entities: [UserEntity],
       synchronize: true, // In production use false
    }),
      ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
    exports: [],
    })
    export class AppModule {}

    // Create entity manually like this...
    // user/entity/user.entity'
    import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

    @Entity({ name: 'User' })
    export class UserEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id', unsigned: true })
    id: number;

    @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
    name: string;

    @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false, length: 50 })
    email: string;

    @Column({ enum: ['USER', 'ADMIN'], default: 'USER' })
    role: 'USER' | 'ADMIN';

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
    createAt: Date;

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
    updateAt: Date;

    @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false, length: 255 })
    password: string;
   }
```